# trying to find transactions with atleast 1 item with transaction amount <= $10

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find the count of distinct transactions, sum of quantity, sum of dollar_value_us and count of distinct individual_id in which atleast one Item is >=$10 value. I have created a sql databse. also I am trying to break the dollar_value_us in ranges

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e1ee5e9a6264d758f4a7480fa8d6b964

Sample data:

```
individual_id | dollar_value_us | quantity | transaction_number | sku    | txn_date            | brand_org_code | is_merch | currency_code | line_item_amt_type_cd
------------: | --------------: | -------: | -----------------: | :----- | :------------------ | :------------- | -------: | :------------ | :--------------------
            1 |              10 |       30 |                567 | 903633 | 02/01/2019 00:00:00 | BRAND          |        1 | USD           | S                    
            1 |              20 |       30 |                567 | 123767 | 02/01/2019 00:00:00 | BRAND          |        1 | USD           | S                    
            2 |              11 |       80 |                910 | 363635 | 02/11/2019 00:00:00 | BRAND          |        1 | USD           | S                    
            3 |               9 |       62 |                855 | 678364 | 02/12/2019 00:00:00 | BRAND          |        1 | USD           | S
```

this is the sample of how the output should look:
[image]

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: You tagged your question oracle but you provided a SQLServer fiddlde. Which one are you using?

Comment: I am using oracle. But I created a sample on sql server by mistake sorry baout that

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55484621/edit) to include an expected output for your sample data.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question to show the  expected result structure, that makes things clearer. Now you would also need to show us the actual data in the structure, that corresponds to your sample data...

Comment: that is the actual data structure. my actual data is the same what I have in the sample database. The only difference is that I am using oracle

Comment: @Somiya... I meant: would you please edit your answer to show the expected output that corresponds to your input data (not just an empty resultset structure)?

Comment: @GMB I added the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
select Dollar_Range, count(distinct individual_id), count(*), sum(quantity)
from (select t.*,
             (case when dollar_value_us < 10 then 'below $10'
                   when dollar_value_us < 20 then '$10 - $20'
                   when dollar_value_us < 30 then '$20 - $30'
                   when dollar_value_us < 40 then '$30 - $40'
                   when dollar_value_us < 50 then '$40 - $50'
                   else '$50 - above'
            end) as dollar_range
      from t
     ) t
group by dollar_range
order by min(dollar_value_us);
```

Comment: @SomiyaL . . . And how does it not work.  Your comment is not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 'below $10' as Dollar_Range count(individual_id), count(transaction_number), sum(quantity) from myData where dollar_value_us < 10
union
select '$10 - $20' as Dollar_Range count(individual_id), count(transaction_number), sum(quantity) from myData where dollar_value_us >=10 and dollar_value_us < 20
union
select '$20 - $30' as Dollar_Range count(individual_id), count(transaction_number), sum(quantity) from myData where dollar_value_us >=20 and dollar_value_us < 30
union
select '$30 - $40' as Dollar_Range count(individual_id), count(transaction_number), sum(quantity) from myData where dollar_value_us >=30 and dollar_value_us < 40
union
select '$40 - $50' as Dollar_Range count(individual_id), count(transaction_number), sum(quantity) from myData where dollar_value_us >= 40 and dollar_value_us < 50
union
select '$50 - above' as Dollar_Range count(individual_id), count(transaction_number), sum(quantity) from myData where dollar_value_us >50
```